How to get a cleaned dataframe after using ydata-profiling on it?
I know it won't probably be perfectly cleaned (since it it an automated task) but I would like to understand how to get the cleaned dataframe (not the original) after the original has been processed by ydata-profiling.
I can't find it in the JSON report.
It is cleaned but the clean dataframe is not present in the profiling JSON report (there is only a little sample with head and tail).

As far as I know, ydata-profiling does not provide a "clean" dataset. Cleaning it's up to you basing on the analysis you can do with the report.
ydata-profiling is a leading package for data profiling, that automates and standardizes the generation of detailed reports, complete with statistics and visualizations. The significance of the package lies in how it streamlines the process of understanding and preparing data for analysis in a single line of code! (source: https://docs.profiling.ydata.ai/latest/)
